# Can you help to solve error in react-native

Tags: reactjs, react-native

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:installDebug'.

  > com.android.builder.testing.api.DeviceException: com.android.ddmlib.InstallException: Unknown failure: cmd: Can't find service: package
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at [gradle](https://help.gradle.org)

BUILD FAILED in 17s

Comment: Try to cool boot the emulator

Comment: how to boot emulator

Comment: Check my answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Close** all the running emulators if any

Go to Android Studio and open **AVD Manager**

From that click your device and make **Cool Boot Now** and re-run your application

[image]

Once you click **Cool Boot Now** emulator will open again like this

[image]

Comment: when I click , it is sleep

Comment: @IamEarn close your all running emulators and try this

Comment: Hello ,the development server returned response error code 500 How to solve?

Comment: Unistall the application and close all running metro bundlers and try again

Comment: Hello, How to login with facebook in snack.expo.io